# jQuery not working on my host?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery, hosting

I am working on a site, and everything is working in my local environment as well as on a test server I have here and everything works fine.  *but* when I upload it to my host, nothing seems to work!?

The Asp.Net javascript validators fire, but any and all of the jquery is not working?  I even put in a simple

```
$("#test").html("working");
```

and

```
<div id="test></div>
```

And nothing is happening?  I have triple checked that all the js is uploaded (to my /js/ directory

The site is here: http://whoowes.me (it is in it's infancy still... barely started) and the Login/Register/Contact buttons should all pull a modal popup (not change pages, that should only happen if JS is disabled) and the word 'test' should show up under the menu.

Can JS be disabled from the server? Wouldn't make sense though as the asp.net javascript validators are showing up?

I am completely confused here, any ideas would be great!

Comment: Not to snoop around, but where is the jQuery file?  Is it in the root directory?  Do you have some kind of routing set up for js files?

Comment: BTW - I think the idea for your site is great.

Comment: Side Idea is indeed fantastic.

Comment: I know it is a late answer but i didn't see anyone mention this in their answers. Could it be that it does not work because of the missing '"' char of the div id? It is always these kind of mistakes that make us go crazy for a couple of days re-installing and re-debugging things we do not have to. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my host did not default to have .js in their MIME types, so I had to add it in:

```
extension: .js

application/x-javascript
```

Comment: Sorry for ressurecting an old post - But how exactly did you go about this? Is it doing type="application/x-javascript" ??

Answer (score 7):

You could always let Google do your work for you:

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

One pleasant side-effect is that you'll save a little bandwidth, and because many sites now use Google's AJAX API, many users will already have it cached in their browser.

Comment: I had the same problem with naspinski, why that could happen in our host?

Answer (score 3):

```
<script src="/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

http://whoowes.me/jquery.js = 404

Maybe you didn't upload the file to the right place?

(you're not pointing to the `/js/` folder)

Comment: I changed it so the script registration shows... and it still isn't working - I get a 404 if I try to browse to /js/jquery.js

Does that mean it isn't there?  I know that sounds dumb, but it shows up in ftp?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    ...
});
```

surrounding your existing code.

Answer (score 1):

The way the site may be configured on IIS is via their virtual directory setup that may not be including you js folder. The server may also not be allowing the site to deliver the js based on file permissions.

I'd say you put a ticket into your webhosting provider and have them look at why the server is not delivering the file. Another option is the IIS server is not set to allow delivery of the js file extension.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The file whoowes.me/jquery.js can not be found. Make sure you use the right file path in the script tag.